# How to round to 0.25 or 0.75, but not 0.00 or 0.50 in R?

Tags: r, rounding

I'm using R and I want to round my data to the nearest **0.25** or **0.75**, but not including 0.00 or 0.50.

For example, if I wanted to round to the nearest 0.00 or 0.50, I would do as follows:

```
test <- seq(1,10,0.33) 
[1] 1.00 1.33 1.66 1.99 2.32 2.65 2.98 3.31 3.64 3.97 4.30 4.63 4.96 5.29 5.62 5.95 6.28 6.61 6.94 7.27 7.60 7.93 8.26 8.59 8.92 9.25 9.58 9.91
```

Round to 0.00 or 0.50:

```
round(test * 2)/2
[1]  1.0  1.5  1.5  2.0  2.5  2.5  3.0  3.5  3.5  4.0  4.5  4.5  5.0  5.5  5.5  6.0  6.5  6.5  7.0  7.5  7.5  8.0  8.5  8.5  9.0  9.0  9.5 10.0
```

I could do the same for multiples of 0.25. What could I do to round these numbers to 0.25 or 0.75 exclusively, excluding 0.50 and 0.00?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `round((test + 0.25) * 2) / 2 - 0.25`? For your `test`, it gives:

```
# [1] 0.75 1.25 1.75 1.75 2.25 2.75 2.75 3.25 3.75 3.75 4.25 4.75 4.75 5.25 5.75
#[16] 5.75 6.25 6.75 6.75 7.25 7.75 7.75 8.25 8.75 8.75 9.25 9.75 9.75
```

You may also do `round((test - 0.25) * 2) / 2 + 0.25`, giving

```
# [1] 1.25 1.25 1.75 1.75 2.25 2.75 2.75 3.25 3.75 3.75 4.25 4.75 4.75 5.25 5.75
#[16] 5.75 6.25 6.75 6.75 7.25 7.75 7.75 8.25 8.75 8.75 9.25 9.75 9.75
```

The behaviour differs at the round-off direction for whole number. Take `1` as an example. In the first case, it is rounded down to `0.75`, while in the second case, it is rounded up to `1.25`. Whole number is a "grey area" here; you need decide what direction you want.

Comment: It seems to round down 1.0 to 0.75 in your results?

Comment: Good solution. It appears I need to determine where I want the 0.00 and 0.50 to go.

Comment: You might also consider expressions like `0.5*floor(2.0*x) + 0.25` and `0.5*ceil(2.0*x) - 0.25`, both of which round to the nearest `XXX.25` or `XXX.75` value, but have different behaviour in the half-integer edge cases: the first always rounds integers and half-integers up (i.e., towards positive infinity); the second always rounds them down (towards negative infinity).

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I wrote some [bc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_(programming_language)) functions to allow rounding numbers to the nearest specified value with an optional offset, as well as supporting the six common types of [tiebreaking rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking). For your question, I've tried to port my code to R.

There's a significant caveat here related to precision. Since R uses floating-point encoding to represent fractional numbers, you can very easily end up with insufficient precision to properly apply the tiebreaking rules. This is caused by the fact that the difference between the unadjusted rounding result and the rounding interval can deviate from half a unit simply due to floating-point error, and so it can become undetectable whether tiebreaking should be applied at all. This was not a problem for my original code because bc is an infinite precision calculator, but it's a problem in R. I tried to mitigate this problem by doing the calculations with a lenient tolerance, but it's not perfect. If the order of magnitude of the rounding interval differs too greatly from the order of magnitude of the value-to-be-rounded, then the result will be incorrect. But, it should be mentioned, this caveat applies to any solution that uses floating-point arithmetic, not just my code.

Anyway, here's what I've got:

```
FTOL <- 1e-8;
feq <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),abs(a-b)<=max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a==b);
fne <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),abs(a-b)>max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a!=b);
fgt <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),a-b>max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a>b);
fge <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),a-b>=-max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a>=b);
flt <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),b-a>max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a<b);
fle <- function(a,b,tol=FTOL) ifelse(is.finite(a) & is.finite(b),b-a>=-max(abs(a),abs(b))*tol,a<=b);

HALFRULE_UP   <- 1L; ## round towards +Inf
HALFRULE_DOWN <- 2L; ## round towards -Inf
HALFRULE_IN   <- 3L; ## round towards zero
HALFRULE_OUT  <- 4L; ## round away from zero
HALFRULE_EVEN <- 5L; ## round to the even multiple of the two multiples of nearest that are tied
HALFRULE_ODD  <- 6L; ## round to the odd multiple of the two multiples of nearest that are tied
nearest <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0,halfrule=HALFRULE_EVEN) {

    ## ensure correct types
    x <- as.double(x);
    nearest <- as.double(nearest);
    offset <- as.double(offset);
    halfrule <- as.integer(halfrule);

    ## validate
    v <- which(!halfrule%in%c(HALFRULE_UP,HALFRULE_DOWN,HALFRULE_IN,HALFRULE_OUT,HALFRULE_EVEN,HALFRULE_ODD)); if (length(v)>0L) stop(paste0('invalid halfrule: ',halfrule[v[1L]],'.'));

    ## normalize lengths
    len <- max(length(x),length(nearest),length(halfrule));
    x <- rep(x,len=len);
    nearest <- rep(nearest,len=len);
    offset <- rep(offset,len=len);
    halfrule <- rep(halfrule,len=len);

    ## apply offset
    x <- x-offset;

    ## must treat zero nearests different from non-zero
    nonzero <- fne(nearest,0);

    ## start building result
    res <- double(length(x));

    ## nearest zero doesn't really make any sense; but you can consider every possible number to be at the nearest zero
    res[!nonzero] <- x[!nonzero];

    ## simplify subsequent operations to only focus on non-zero nearest
    x <- x[nonzero];
    nearest <- nearest[nonzero];
    halfrule <- halfrule[nonzero];
    offset <- offset[nonzero];

    ## don't care about negativity of nearest
    nearest <- abs(nearest);

    ## get how many times nearest goes into x, truncated
    mult <- as.integer(x/nearest); ## note: can't use %/%, since that actually floors toward -Inf

    ## get round-truncated result
    r.trunc <- mult*nearest;

    ## get absolute excess over r.trunc
    excess <- abs(x - r.trunc);

    ## get half of nearest
    half.of.nearest <- nearest*0.5;

    ## add one to mult if necessary; whether we need to do this in the case of a tie depends on the specified tiebreaker rule and which side of the zero multiple x is on
    adds <- which(
        fgt(excess,half.of.nearest)
        | feq(excess,half.of.nearest) & (
            halfrule==HALFRULE_UP & fgt(x,0)
            | halfrule==HALFRULE_DOWN & flt(x,0)
            | halfrule==HALFRULE_OUT
            | halfrule==HALFRULE_EVEN & mult%%2L!=0L
            | halfrule==HALFRULE_ODD & mult%%2L==0L
        )
    );
    mult[adds] <- mult[adds] + ifelse(flt(x[adds],0),-1,1);

    ## recover target value from mult, and at the same time unshift offset
    res[nonzero] <- nearest*mult+offset;

    res;

}; ## end nearest()
nearest.halfup   <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_UP  );
nearest.halfdown <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_DOWN);
nearest.halfin   <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_IN  );
nearest.halfout  <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_OUT );
nearest.halfeven <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_EVEN);
nearest.halfodd  <- function(x,nearest=1,offset=0) nearest(x,nearest,offset,HALFRULE_ODD );
```

---

For your example input, we need to round to the nearest 0.5 with an offset of 0.25:

```
nearest(seq(1,10,0.33),0.5,0.25);
##  [1] 1.25 1.25 1.75 1.75 2.25 2.75 2.75 3.25 3.75 3.75 4.25 4.75 4.75 5.25 5.75 5.75 6.25
## [18] 6.75 6.75 7.25 7.75 7.75 8.25 8.75 8.75 9.25 9.75 9.75
```

Comment: I guess, to avoid the macro-like definitions, the `HALFRULE_X`s could be, just, wrapped in a "character" vector as the default of "halfrule" argument of `nearest` and use a `match.arg` inside the function.